# MONO ASP.NET Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request

Tags: c#, asp.net, ubuntu, mono

I try to deploy a ASP NET 4.5 Website written in Visual Studio to a Mono Server. And have error in mono.

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.

Exception stack trace:

```html
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_ExitCode () <0x40e8feb0 + 0x000a3> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:get_ExitCode ()
  at System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.InternalExecWaitWithCapture (System.String cmd, System.String currentDir, System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection tempFiles, System.String& outputName, System.String& errorName) <0x40e9d2f0 + 0x00423> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCapture (IntPtr userToken, System.String cmd, System.String currentDir, System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection tempFiles, System.String& outputName, System.String& errorName) <0x40e9d010 + 0x00057> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.Compile (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String compilerFullPath, System.String arguments, System.String& outputFile, System.Int32& nativeReturnValue) <0x40e9cbd0 + 0x0010b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.FromFileBatch (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) <0x40e99470 + 0x00617> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.CompileAssemblyFromFileBatch (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) <0x40e992d0 + 0x000c7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) <0x40e99120 + 0x0004d> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath, System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options) <0x40e843e0 + 0x009a5> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) <0x40e843a0 + 0x00023> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GenerateAssembly (System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder abuilder, System.Web.Compilation.BuildProviderGroup group, System.Web.VirtualPath vp, Boolean debug) <0x40e796c0 + 0x009bf> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BuildInner (System.Web.VirtualPath vp, Boolean debug) <0x40e22710 + 0x0052b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.Build (System.Web.VirtualPath vp) <0x40e220a0 + 0x0011b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) <0x40e21350 + 0x00093> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.String virtualPath) <0x40e20f70 + 0x00017> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.InitType (System.Web.HttpContext context) <0x40e048a0 + 0x0042b> in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: could you post some source please? you might also want to have a look at [ask]

Comment: I have a similar issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42429313/deploying-asp-net-web-forms-project-to-fedora-24) for some reference