# Deploying ASP.Net Web Forms project to Fedora 24

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, apache, nginx

Here is my current setup:

- My Local Computer: This is where I created and programmed my ASP.Net WebForms project with Cloudflare Flexible SSL enabled using visual studio 2015 professional on Windows 10. I also have the team explorer enabled meaning my project is synced to Github and all of my files are also stored there in my own repository.
- My Server Computer: Running Fedora 24, I've installed <s>the dotnet CLI (a.k.a .Net Core),</s> apache (httpd), nginx, and [Mono for ASP.Net](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/aspnet/). I want to deploy/publish and host my webforms project on this computer in the default web directory (/var/www/html/mysite/)

The problem is, the dotnet cli relies on a `project.json` and **is not compatible with WebForms**. .Net Core is basically **not an option**. When I use mod_mono, I get an `Error 500` (see below) if I connect to https://localhost:9000/ while running the server using the command `xsp4 --port 9000`. I can't use `xsp4 --port 80` or `xsp4 --port 443` because then it claims `Address is already in use` even though `httpd` is the only process listening on those ports. ***Note that I can sucessfully build the project using the*** `xbuild` ***command***.

How can I take my project from github or my local computer and deploy it on to my server computer? Am I missing something? Here is my virtual hosts configuration for reference: [httpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/JBeDNT8q). **I typically get no errors when starting httpd.service.**

**EDIT:**

I've also used `nginx` with `fastcgi-mono-server4`  with [this](http://pastebin.com/cUt1ZMFv) configuration instead with nginx, which I got straight from [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/mono/), but still no luck. I usually get this `Error 500`:[image: error] other times I can get other types of `Error 500`. If there is a solution that works with either apache or nginx, please let me know.

Comment: Are Web Forms even compatible with asp.net core? Is the Friendly URLs NuGet package compatible as well? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/06/27/announcing-asp-net-core-1-0/ seems to suggest Web Forms will remain in the .Net 4.x framework.

Comment: @DafyddNZ Yea, that's the problem. I just quit on asp.net core, I've  been trying to use httpd with mod_mono but that's not working either. Now I'm using nginx but I get the error above

Comment: Looking at the Mono for asp.net link you provided, it talks about asp.net 2.0. What .Net framework are you targeting?

Comment: @DafyddNZ 4.5.2

Comment: There is a compatibility page here: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/, if you are using any async patterns they will not be supported by mono. ASP.Net 4.0 is fully compatible though, so you might consider downgrading to that framework.

Comment: @DafyddNZ I haven't added anything that is `async`, and I'm not using MVC, so unless there are `async` operations, that should not be a problem. The errr I'm getting is from `System.web`, and I was having problems earlier with the mono assembly `System.web` not being the same as the windows .Net Framework assembly `System.web`, but I fixed that problem by replacing the former with the latter.

Comment: From your latest error message, it looks like duplicate of route AspNet.FriendlyUrls.SwitchView gets added again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is *Full NET* and not even *NET Core* and trying to deploy it to *Mono Framework*. This may not work, Convert your project into *Mono* or *NET Core* and retry.

Comment: .Net Core is not compatible with Web Forms. I can't change the framework on an existing project, and if I make a new project targeting .Net Core, it creates it in a completely new and unfamiliar format

Comment: You may want to try [windows docker container](https://www.docker.com/microsoft) in ubuntu to host unmodifed app. Am not 100% sure as this is not yet in practice

Comment: Have a look [here](http://blog.alexellis.io/run-iis-asp-net-on-windows-10-with-docker/). User tried to run IIS ASP.NET on Windows Server docker image. Maybe if I get time will tryout same and post on my blog this weekend.

Comment: That's on windows 10...I'm running Fedora Linux, that's the problem

Comment: You may consider having a virtual machine inside fedora and have windows docker in it. Virtual OS maybe a "Container OS" in case we're short on resource. Apologies for not considering linux system on the first hand.